# Please don't use local timestamps in app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, timestamps

See this screenshot please:

> [image]

The timestamp is showing in my local language which is a right-to-left language. This cause the time and date to be totally messed up.

I would be happy with forcing the same timestamp format as on the desktop site and think it would make sense. Can this be done?

Comment: I think it's doable, I'll take a look

Comment: Thanks a lot, highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All date formatting will now follow the en_US locale, so you will no longer see the Israeli date formatting. The change will take effect in **version 0.1.26.**

Comment: Awesome, looking forward for the new version release! :)